# Regular Expression for Whole Number (Thousands comma, No decimal)

Tags: regex, validation

I need to validate an input filter on a form because I cannot format the output due to the template I am using.  This is a price field and I need the output to be uniform. I am able to use a regular expression to validate the input.

I would like regex to be a whole number with thousands separated with a comma. No decimal. No $.

Valid:

```
* 0 (just zero) 
* 100
* 1,000 
* 10,000
```

Not Valid:

- 01 (leading zero)
- 100.50
- 1000
- $10,000
- -10,000 (no negative number)

Does anyone know how to do this? I cannot find this and thought it should be a common regex.

Comment: Start [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean) and come back to us once you have a decent attempt to show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need something similar to,

Using **javascript**

```
^(0|[1-9][0-9]{0,2})(,[0-9]{3})*$
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this regex:
`^(0|[1-9][0-9]{0,2})(,[0-9]{3})*$`

Below is a python implementation:

```
import re
regex = r"^(0|[1-9][0-9]{0,2})(,[0-9]{3})*$"
num = "10,000"
if re.search(regex, num):
  print(True)
else:
  print(False)
```